# Xampp localhost/dashboard

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, dashboard

I downloaded the recent version of xampp and I installed it and everything but when i type "localhost" in the browser it redirects me to localhost/dashboard is there a way to type localhost and see the directories and files like before?

there was some versions of xampp where you just have to change the name of the index.php or delete it and you could see the directories and files in localhost from the browser

does someone knows which versions are? or how to solve the problem?

Comment: you have to edit php config file

Comment: did you start xampp(apache/mysql) after installation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to display directory than edit `htdocs/index.php` file

Below code is display all directory in table

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Welcome to Nims Server</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="server/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- START PAGE SOURCE -->
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="top">
    <h1 id="sitename">Nims <em>Server</em> Directory list</h1>
    <div id="searchbar">
      <form action="#">
        <div id="searchfield">
          <input type="text" name="keyword" class="keyword" />
          <input class="searchbutton" type="image" src="server/images/searchgo.gif"  alt="search" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="background">
<div class="transbox">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="5" style="border:0px solid #333333;background: #F9F9F9;"> 
<tr>
<?php
//echo md5("saketbook007");

//File functuion DIR is used here.
$d = dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); 
$i=-1;
//Loop start with read function
while ($entry = $d->read()) {
if($entry == "." || $entry ==".."){
}else{
?>
<td  class="site" width="33%"><a href="<?php echo $entry;?>" ><?php echo ucfirst($entry); ?></a></td>  
<?php 
}
if($i%3 == 0){
echo "</tr><tr>";
}
$i++;
}?>
</tr> 
</table>

<?php $d->close();
?> 

</div>
</div>
</div>
   </div></div></body>
</html>
```

Style:

```
@import url("fontface.css");
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}

body {
    background:url(images/bg.jpg) repeat;
    font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    color:#212713;
}
#wrap {
    width:1300px;
    margin:auto;
}

#sitename {
    font: normal 46px chunk;
    color:#1b2502;
    text-shadow:#5d7a17 1px 1px 1px;
    display:block;
    padding:45px 0 0 0;
    width:60%;
    float:left;
}
#searchbar {
    width:39%;
    float:right;
}
#sitename em {
    font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
}
#top {
    height:145px;
}
img {

    width:90%;
    height:250px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:0 0 0 50px;
}


.post h2 a {
    color:#656f42;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#searchbar {
    padding:55px 0 0 0;
}
#searchfield {
    background:url(images/searchbar.gif) no-repeat;
    width:239px;
    height:35px;
    float:right;
}
#searchfield .keyword {
    width:170px;
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
    padding:8px 0 0 10px;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
#searchfield .searchbutton {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:7px 0 0 5px;
}

div.background
{
  background:url(h.jpg) repeat-x;
  border: 2px solid black;

  width:99%;
}
div.transbox
{
  margin: 15px;
  background-color: #ffffff;

  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity:0.8;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  height:500px;
}

.site{

border:1px solid #CCC; 
}

.site a{text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold; color:#000; line-height:2}
.site:hover{background:#000; border:1px solid #03C;}
.site:hover a{color:#FFF}
```

Output :
[image]

Comment: thanks I tried to modify the index.php but it wasn't working i suppose something was wrong with my code this worked

Comment: Welcome @Alberto :)

Answer (score 4):

Wanna a list of folder in xampp?

Just delete or change the file index.php to index.txt. 
And you will get the list just typing url: localhost.

[image: Browser screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

Go to->

1. xammp ->htdocs-> then open index.php from the htdocs folder
2. you can modify the dashboard
3. restart the server

Example Code index.php :

```
    <?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');
    exit;
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Type in your URL localhost/[name of your folder in htdocs]

Comment: Yeah i knew that but i wanted to type in the url "localhost" and display all the files and directories not type the entire url but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's actually happening
localhost means that you want to open htdocs.
First it will search for any file named index.php or index.html. If one of those exist it will open the file.
If neither of those exist then it will open all folder/file inside htdocs directory which is what you want.

So, the simplest solution is to rename index.php or index.html to index2.php etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just create file `index.php` and save it to: `C:\xampp\htdocs\`

Like User Matiur Rahman. Thanks, it works for me. You can copy this script and paste it into your `index.php` file.

```
<?php
   if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    $uri = 'https://';
   } else {
    $uri = 'http://';
   }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
   header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');
   exit;
?>
```